# Your project config YAML files are expecting different versions to be installed

Tags: composer, projectconfig, project.yaml

I'm working on a site on shared hosting and I can't run `composer install` from CLI to install the vendor folder because I get

> The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation

and `proc_open` can't be enabled because it's a security risk.

I can upload the vendor folder from my local and everything works fine but when I go to apply YAML changes, I get:

> Your project config YAML files are expecting different versions to be installed
> Try running `composer install` from your terminal to resolve.

With the vendor folder already in place, if I run `composer install` I get everything is up to date. I've tried running `composer dump-autoload` and then `composer install` and get the same thing.

So how can I get around this so that I can apply the latest project config changes?

Comment: When I rebuild the project config, the schema version changes(fixed the issue), but also it has an impact on multiple files. For example, in the 'servd\AssetStorage\AssetsPlatform\Fs' type, the subfolder path value changes from 'staging/images' to 'local/images' in the 'project.yml' file. Is this potentially dangerous for the live site because the path now indicates the local file path, and the 'changedFieldIndicator' value of supertable plugin is set to null? [![subfolder Path is changed from staging to live](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDsbW.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDsbW.png) [![change

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That error occurs when there is a discrepancy between the schema versions listed in your incoming project config YAML, and what’s actually installed.

If you have the site installed locally, try rebuilding the project config (**Utilities** → **Project Config** → **Rebuild**), and then upload the new `config/project/` folder to production.

Comment: That did it, thanks Brandon. 